# How to add Dynamic fields for custom extension at Admin side magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

How to Create Dynamic Generated Field at the admin side in custom extension.

[image]

Comment: by admin side you mean system configuration or on a custom form?

Comment: There are many blogs for system configuration. But I need for a custom extension.

Comment: Is your form Block based or ui component based?

Comment: @PratikKamani  do you need  it in form or system configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can check [magento document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-dynamicrows.html) for dynamic rows in ui component form

```
<form>
...
<dynamicRows name="dynamic_rows">
    <settings>
        <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Record</addButtonLabel>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
        <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
    </settings>
    <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="field_1" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label>Field #1</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="field_2" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label>Field #2</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </container>
  </dynamicRows>
</form>
```